# Can you move the docking station of a complex?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

I made a mistake and my complex has the docking station at the wrong place.
Sales are only going slowly because of that, because it is out of sight of the AI Traders.

**Is there anything I can do to move the docking office or make the AI aware of my new complex so the AI starts buying my products?**

Comment: afaik AI becomes aware of your complexes right away, though they might not buy from you unless the price is good.

Comment: @spartacus There is no spaceweed farm within 10 jumps and my price is 1 credit blow normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but there's a catch.  You will either have to blow up your complex hub and reconnect it all, or add (at least 2) additional stations to your complex.

In order to move the complex via the reconnect method, you first have to place 2 new stations, then form a second complex with those 2 stations while placing the docking hub at where you want the new location to be.  Finally, you use a second complex construction kit (select your new hub location first!) and connect the new one with the old one.

Also, the location of the docking station becomes less important if you are out of the sector as no maneuvering takes place for ships to dock.

Comment: How would blowing it up work? About importance: The hub is behind the western stargate, since it was the only suitable asteroid there. Sales are really going slow, the space weed is full and nobody buys it, quite contrary to my other, way smaller complex where it is gone the moment it is produced. I know that the AI is only buying if it discovers the new station. How can I help that and make the AI aware of my complex as alternative? I edited my question.

Comment: @user28015 when you blow up the hub, all your stations will become disconnected.  Did you adjust the price of the space weed?  I never noticed an issue selling it if you set the sell price to be average-1.  It may just take some time for ships to arrive but once they do it'll run out quick.

Comment: @User28015 also, in the future, you can buy a tractor beam (search paranid core sectors for the factory that makes them) and use it to tow asteroids to more suitable locations.

Comment: I know, I have my own TL which has one, but I was playing deep in the night and built the complex into the wrong direction, so it faced away from the stargate instead of into the sector etc. It was late, I was tired and didnt think much hehe. That happens once in a while ;). I don't have a save that is not too far behind though. Well, anyway, so I blow up the docking office and then all stations become disconnected? So I just buy new connectors and reconnect?

Comment: @user28015 that's right